# Maven multi module child pom version

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

While I was learning about maven multi module , I have a doubt.

Does it makes sense for a child module to have a  different version than parent module ? In what case , for example ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you try to avoid that. While it may make sense from a logical perspective (avoid to change the version number of a module that did not change), you get into a complicated logic of when to rebuild what and which version uses which version of which other module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It makes sense when child module is deployed independently also, and it's version ranging differently.